# Android - when is performTraversals called?

Tags: android, view

I'm curious guys,

What are the exact cases `doTraversal -> performTraversals` is called? Since I have pretty heavy Activity, I want the application to call `onDraw` or the sort. performTraversals is pretty heavy, it is trying/measuring if it should resize views, stuff like that I guess. And I don't need it when I'm making some view, that no other view is dependent on, GONE, but I guess I can't skip that. So before digging into the source of Android, I want to ask. If you know it, please feel free to share :)

Thanks,
Danail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`performTraversals()` has many jobs but its three main roles are:

- Measure views
- Layout views
- Draw views

Every time Android needs to redraw a window, `performTraversals()` is invoked. It does not mean however that measure/layout happens every time performTraversals() executes. You *cannot* skip `performTraversals()` if you are using a standard views (only SurfaceView lets you bypass this when drawing.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does that mean if I make some View visibility GONE - performTraversals for all views in the ViewRootImpl will be called? I mean touching any View in this way (making it GONE, not VISIBILITY)

Comment: Why do you need it gone, not just invisible? Of course making view "gone" triggers relayout. Just like any other layout-related action.

Comment: because of animations. If I made it gone at the end of the animation, the other view (which is part of the animated layout) goes to the right place. If I make it invisible, there will be weird empty window where it should not be. WIth GONE I don't need to change the layout settings.

Comment: This view only affects one other view when it is GONE. But it triggers a lot of other unnecessary actions and estimations. This is why I'm trying to get better grasp of the way Android works, so I can optimize my code.